# How to add pagination in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, pagination

How can I enable WordPress pagination on my home page? I have limited the number of posts shown in the page. Do I need to put any code to show the pagination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using something similar to:

```
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="alignleft"><? next_posts_link('&laquo; Previous') ?>
  </div>
  <div class="alignright"><? previous_posts_link('Next') ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your support. I have solved it using a plugin "wp-paginate". its working in home page. But not woring in category page :(

Answer (score 0):

Frabiacca has it right.

```
<?php next_posts_link($label , $max_pages); ?>
<?php prev_posts_link($label , $max_pages); ?>
```

Also remember that previous is actually WP speak for newer posts not older posts. can be a little confusing.